# Water leaking from in ground PVC in front lawn, is this normal?

Tags: water, pvc, lawn, leaking

We are experiencing some water leaking from the PVC pipes in the front lawn. Is this normal or do we need to address this issue? The water does not appear to smell but we can tell it’s been happening for sometime since there is green algae forming on the rocks.

[image]

Comment: Looks like some drainage system that's clogged. Remove that cap and see if you can see more. You might have to snake it.

Comment: What size is the pipe?

Comment: Probably the end of a soakaway connected to downspouts or sump pump outlet. Where is it, relative to your house?

Comment: what is that white globe